# Unable to read data from Redis using NodeJS TypeScript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, casbin

I'm making a call to the method called loadFilteredPolicy() by passing the filter object which is my hashkey from client side but its method get() or hgetall() never get executed and control goes out without fetch the data from Redis server without throwing any error. Let me confirm you that I can debug and can assure that there is an object of redis on this.redisInstance but not sure why then method do not execute. I can fetch the same data directly using the redis-cli by the command **hgetall** .

One more thing I want to tell you is that when I uncomment Promise line just above (await this.redisInstance.hgetall) and debug again then this.redisInstance returns undefined. I'm not sure what is happening. I have worked with JS before but not much TypeScript and I'm stuck in this error since Morning and now it is evening.

This is my TypeScript code (adapter.ts) which gets compiled to JS file :-

```
import { Helper, Model, FilteredAdapter } from 'casbin';
import * as redis from 'redis';

interface IConnectionOptions {
    host: string;
    port: number;
}
class Line {
    ptype: string;
    v0: string;
    v1: string;
    v2: string;
    v3: string;
    v4: string;
    v5: string;
}
export class RedisAdapter implements FilteredAdapter {

    private redisInstance = null;
    private policies = null;
    private filtered = false;

    public isFiltered(): boolean {
        return this.filtered;
    }

    private deliveredOptions = {
        retry_strategy(options) {
            if (options.error && options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
                return new Error('The server refused the connection');
            }
            if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
                return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
            }
            if (options.attempt > 10) {
                return undefined;
            }
            // reconnect after
            return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 300);
        },
    };

    /**
     * Helper Methods
     */

    savePolicyLine(ptype, rule) {
        const line = new Line();
        line.ptype = ptype;
        if (rule.length > 0) {
            line.v0 = rule[0];
        }

        if (rule.length > 1) {
            line.v1 = rule[1];
        }

        if (rule.length > 2) {
            line.v2 = rule[2];
        }

        if (rule.length > 3) {
            line.v3 = rule[3];
        }

        if (rule.length > 4) {
            line.v4 = rule[4];
        }

        if (rule.length > 5) {
            line.v5 = rule[5];
        }
        return line;
    }
    loadPolicyLine(line, model) {
        console.log("load Policies line called");
        let lineText = line.ptype;
        if (line.v0) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v0;
        }
        if (line.v1) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v1;
        }
        if (line.v2) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v2;
        }
        if (line.v3) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v3;
        }
        if (line.v4) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v4;
        }
        if (line.v5) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v5;
        }
        Helper.loadPolicyLine(lineText, model);
    }

    storePolicies(policies) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log({ r: this.redisInstance });
            this.redisInstance.del('policies');
            this.redisInstance.set('policies', JSON.stringify(policies), (err, reply) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(reply);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    reducePolicies(policies, ptype, rule) {
        let i = rule.length;
        let policyIndex = policies.fieldIndex((policy) => {
            let flag = false;
            flag = policy.ptype === ptype ? true : false;
            flag = i > 5 && policy.v5 === rule[5] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 4 && policy.v4 === rule[4] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 3 && policy.v3 === rule[3] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 2 && policy.v2 === rule[2] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 1 && policy.v0 === rule[1] ? true : false;
            return flag;
        });
        if (policyIndex !== -1) {
            return policies.splice(policyIndex, 1);
        }
        return [];
    }

    constructor(options: IConnectionOptions) {
        this.redisInstance = redis.createClient(
            {
                ...options,
                ...this.deliveredOptions,
            },
        );
    }

    static async newAdapter(options: IConnectionOptions) {
        const adapter = new RedisAdapter(options);
        await new Promise(resolve => adapter.redisInstance.on('connect', resolve));
        return adapter;
    }

    /**
     * Adapter Methods
     */
    public async loadPolicy(model) {
        this.redisInstance.get("policies", (err, policies) => {
            var AdapterRef = this;
            console.log("Loading Policies...\n", policies);
            if (!err) {
                policies = JSON.parse(policies);
                this.policies = policies;//For add and remove policies methods
                console.log(policies);
                policies.forEach(function (policy, index) {
                    AdapterRef.loadPolicyLine(policy, model);
                });
                console.log("Policies are loaded");
            } else {
                return err;
            }
        });
    }

    public async loadFilteredPolicy(model: Model, filter: object): Promise<void> {
        let key = filter['hashKey'];
        //return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            this.redisInstance.hgetall(key, (err, policies) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(err);
                    var AdapterRef = this;
                    console.log("Loading filtered Policies...\n", policies);
                    policies = JSON.parse(policies);
                    this.policies = policies;//For add and remove policies methods
                    console.log(policies);
                    policies.forEach(function (policy, index) {
                        AdapterRef.loadPolicyLine(policy, model);
                    });
                    console.log("Filtered Policies are loaded...");
                    this.filtered = true;
                }
            });
        //})
    }

    public async savePolicy(model: Model): Promise<boolean> {
        const policyRuleAST = model.model.get("p");
        const groupingPolicyAST = model.model.get("g");
        let policies = [];

        //var rows2 = <Array<any>>policyRuleAST;
        //var rows2 = <Array<any>>groupingPolicyAST;

        for (const [ptype, ast] of Object.entries(policyRuleAST)) {
            for (const rule of ast.policy) {
                const line = this.savePolicyLine(ptype, rule);
                policies.push(line);
            }
        }

        for (const [ptype, ast] of Object.entries(groupingPolicyAST)) {
            for (const rule of ast.policy) {
                const line = this.savePolicyLine(ptype, rule);
                policies.push(line);
            }
        }
        //this.storePolicies(policies);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log({ r: this.redisInstance });
            this.redisInstance.del('policies');
            this.redisInstance.set('policies', JSON.stringify(policies), (err, reply) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    async addPolicy(sec, ptype, rule) {
        const line = this.savePolicyLine(ptype, rule);
        this.policies.push(line);
        this.storePolicies(this.policies);
        //reSave the policies
    }

    async removePolicy(sec, ptype, rule) {
        let result = this.reducePolicies(this.policies, ptype, rule);
        //the modified policies
        if (result.length) { //if length>0
            this.policies = result;
            //Store in Redis
            this.storePolicies(this.policies);
        } else {
            // console.IN("No Policy found");
            throw new Error("No Policy Found");
        }
    }

    public async removeFilteredPolicy(sec: string, ptype: string, fieldIndex: number, ...fieldValues: string[]) {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented");
    }
}
```

Corresponding adapter.js :-

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.RedisAdapter = void 0;
const casbin_1 = require("casbin");
const redis = require("redis");
class Line {
}
class RedisAdapter {
    constructor(options) {
        this.redisInstance = null;
        this.policies = null;
        this.filtered = false;
        this.deliveredOptions = {
            retry_strategy(options) {
                if (options.error && options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
                    return new Error('The server refused the connection');
                }
                if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
                    return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
                }
                if (options.attempt > 10) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 300);
            },
        };
        this.redisInstance = redis.createClient(Object.assign(Object.assign({}, options), this.deliveredOptions));
    }
    isFiltered() {
        return this.filtered;
    }
    savePolicyLine(ptype, rule) {
        const line = new Line();
        line.ptype = ptype;
        if (rule.length > 0) {
            line.v0 = rule[0];
        }
        if (rule.length > 1) {
            line.v1 = rule[1];
        }
        if (rule.length > 2) {
            line.v2 = rule[2];
        }
        if (rule.length > 3) {
            line.v3 = rule[3];
        }
        if (rule.length > 4) {
            line.v4 = rule[4];
        }
        if (rule.length > 5) {
            line.v5 = rule[5];
        }
        return line;
    }
    loadPolicyLine(line, model) {
        console.log("load Policies line called");
        let lineText = line.ptype;
        if (line.v0) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v0;
        }
        if (line.v1) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v1;
        }
        if (line.v2) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v2;
        }
        if (line.v3) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v3;
        }
        if (line.v4) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v4;
        }
        if (line.v5) {
            lineText += ", " + line.v5;
        }
        casbin_1.Helper.loadPolicyLine(lineText, model);
    }
    storePolicies(policies) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log({ r: this.redisInstance });
            this.redisInstance.del('policies');
            this.redisInstance.set('policies', JSON.stringify(policies), (err, reply) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(reply);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    reducePolicies(policies, ptype, rule) {
        let i = rule.length;
        let policyIndex = policies.fieldIndex((policy) => {
            let flag = false;
            flag = policy.ptype === ptype ? true : false;
            flag = i > 5 && policy.v5 === rule[5] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 4 && policy.v4 === rule[4] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 3 && policy.v3 === rule[3] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 2 && policy.v2 === rule[2] ? true : false;
            flag = i > 1 && policy.v0 === rule[1] ? true : false;
            return flag;
        });
        if (policyIndex !== -1) {
            return policies.splice(policyIndex, 1);
        }
        return [];
    }
    static async newAdapter(options) {
        const adapter = new RedisAdapter(options);
        await new Promise(resolve => adapter.redisInstance.on('connect', resolve));
        return adapter;
    }
    async loadPolicy(model) {
        this.redisInstance.get("policies", (err, policies) => {
            var AdapterRef = this;
            console.log("Loading Policies...\n", policies);
            if (!err) {
                policies = JSON.parse(policies);
                this.policies = policies;
                console.log(policies);
                policies.forEach(function (policy, index) {
                    AdapterRef.loadPolicyLine(policy, model);
                });
                console.log("Policies are loaded");
            }
            else {
                return err;
            }
        });
    }
    async loadFilteredPolicy(model, filter) {
        let key = filter['hashKey'];
        //await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            await this.redisInstance.hgetall(key, (err, policies) => {
                if (err) {
                    return err;
                }
                else {
                    var AdapterRef = this;
                    console.log("Loading filtered Policies...\n", policies);
                    policies = JSON.parse(policies);
                    this.policies = policies;
                    console.log(policies);
                    policies.forEach(function (policy, index) {
                        AdapterRef.loadPolicyLine(policy, model);
                    });
                    console.log("Filtered Policies are loaded...");
                    this.filtered = true;
                }
            });
       // });
    }
    async savePolicy(model) {
        const policyRuleAST = model.model.get("p");
        const groupingPolicyAST = model.model.get("g");
        let policies = [];
        for (const [ptype, ast] of Object.entries(policyRuleAST)) {
            for (const rule of ast.policy) {
                const line = this.savePolicyLine(ptype, rule);
                policies.push(line);
            }
        }
        for (const [ptype, ast] of Object.entries(groupingPolicyAST)) {
            for (const rule of ast.policy) {
                const line = this.savePolicyLine(ptype, rule);
                policies.push(line);
            }
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log({ r: this.redisInstance });
            this.redisInstance.del('policies');
            this.redisInstance.set('policies', JSON.stringify(policies), (err, reply) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    async addPolicy(sec, ptype, rule) {
        const line = this.savePolicyLine(ptype, rule);
        this.policies.push(line);
        this.storePolicies(this.policies);
    }
    async removePolicy(sec, ptype, rule) {
        let result = this.reducePolicies(this.policies, ptype, rule);
        if (result.length) {
            this.policies = result;
            this.storePolicies(this.policies);
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("No Policy Found");
        }
    }
    async removeFilteredPolicy(sec, ptype, fieldIndex, ...fieldValues) {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented");
    }
}
exports.RedisAdapter = RedisAdapter;
```

I would really appreciate if you can suggest me to make this code work. My GitHub link for this adapter source code is available here https://github.com/vinod827/node-casbin-redis-adapter.git

Thank you,

**[Updated code, not working still]**

```
async loadFilteredPolicy(model, filter) {
    let key = filter['hashKey'];
    let filteredPolicies = await this.getFilteredPolicies(key).then(data => { return data });
    console.log(filteredPolicies);
}
getFilteredPolicies = async (hashKey) => {
    return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        this.redisInstance.hgetall((hashKey), function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        })
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-learn the use of `Promise`, at least you need to know when to use `resolve()`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

By the way, don't use `typescript` as an excuse, only `javascript` here.

I am here to provide you with a minimal implementation that works:

```
import * as redis from "redis";

const client = redis.createClient(6379, "127.0.0.1");

function func() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.hgetall("myhash", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
  const data = await func();
  console.log(data);
}

main();
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I have written promise but still not working. Getting undefined while using Promise for redis instance object. I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below code on https://github.com/vinod827/node-casbin-redis-adapter/blob/master/src/adapter.ts#L150
?

```
public async loadPolicy(model) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reason)=> {
        this.redisInstance.get("policies", (err, policies) => {
            console.log("Loading Policies...\n", policies);
            if (!err) {
                policies = JSON.parse(policies);
                console.log(policies);
                policies.forEach((policy, index)=> {
                    this.loadPolicyLine(policy, model);
                });
                console.log("Policies are loaded");
                resolve()
            } else {
                reason(err)
            }
        });
    })
}
```